# Подсвечивание текущего дня недели?

Tags: jquery

Вывожу графике работы на сайте. Но как получить текущий день недели и применить к списку свой класс, чтоб он подсвечивался

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Понедельник:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Вторник:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Среда:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Четверг:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Пятница:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Суббота:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Воскресение:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ради такой задачи тянуть jQuery бессмысленно, потому проще сделать на чистом JS.

Например, используя [`Date.getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay). Стоит учесть, что в `getDay` неделя начинается с воскресенья, потому воскресенье - 0, понедельник - 1 и так далее. Исходя из этого, можно сделать что-то в этом роде:

```js
let weekDay = new Date().getDay();

document.getElementsByClassName('list-group-item')[weekDay === 0 ? 6 : weekDay-1].classList.add('current')
```

```css
.current {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Понедельник:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Вторник:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Среда:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Четверг:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Пятница:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Суббота:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><b>Воскресение:</b> 10:00–18:00</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Вроде все ок, но показывает что сегодня вторник

Comment: Приношу извинения. Исправил.